# Two's complement confusion

Tags: binary

I have a sign and magnitude representation of 7 (0111). And converting this to two's complement would be (change the 1 to 0 and 0 to 1, then add 1). Which would make:
1000. and then 1001. However in my book and online converters say that it's 0111. So the two's complement is the same for every positive number. Using the method I mentioned however works for the - ones. Why?

Comment: Positive values (e.g. 7) have the same representation in sign+magnitude and 2s complement - it's only negative values that are different. I think you are getting muddled between *converting* between formats and *negating* values (as you described the method for negating a 2s complement value in your question above) ?

Comment: @PaulR oh, so using the method i mentioned is to get a negative in two's complement from the sign and magnitude?

Comment: Almost - the method you describe makes a positive number negative, or a negative number positive (assuming 2s complement). Also, since 1s complement and sign+magnitude also have the same representation as 2s complement for positive values only, it can also be used to generate the negative 2s complement value for positive values in any of these formats.

Comment: @PaulR thank you, one last thing I don't get is then, if i take the sign and magnitude of -2, and get it's 2's complement, why do i get +6?

Comment: Taking the 2s complement of a negative value only makes sense if the representation is 2s complement. -2 in sign+magnitude is 1010, which is -6 in 2s complement, so taking the 2s complement of this will give you +6. (To negate a sign-magnitude value you would normally just invert the sign bit: -2 = 1010 => 0010 = +2)

Comment: Ahhh, okay makes sense. Thanks for the help :) @PaulR